# rJAVA wrong java version

Tags: r, java-8, ubuntu-14.04, rjava

This problem has plagued me for a week now. I have installed rJAVA from R running on a Ubuntu server 14.04. I installed rJava package as source like this:

```
install.packages("rJava", type="source")
```

and I get:

```
DONE(rJava)
```

I have installed `java-8-openjdk` and when running `java -version` I get the correct version and this is the output:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_91"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_91-8u91-b14-0ubuntu4~14.04-b14)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.91-b14, mixed mode)
```

However when I check the java version in R using either

```
sudo R CMD javareconf
```

or

```
library(rJava)
jinit()
.jcall("java/lang/System", "S", "getProperty", "java.runtime.version")
```

The java version is still set to 1.7:

```
Java interpreter : /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/jre/bin/java
Java version     : 1.7.0_101
Java home path   : /usr/lib/jvm/default-java
Java compiler    : /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/bin/javac
Java headers gen.: /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/bin/javah
Java archive tool: /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/bin/jar

trying to compile and link a JNI program 
detected JNI cpp flags    : -I$(JAVA_HOME)/include
detected JNI linker flags : -L/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/server -ljvm
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG -I/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include     -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c conftest.c -o conftest.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -shared -L/usr/lib/R/lib -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -o conftest.so conftest.o -L/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/server -ljvm -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR


JAVA_HOME        : /usr/lib/jvm/default-java
Java library path: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/server
JNI cpp flags    : -I$(JAVA_HOME)/include
JNI linker flags : -L/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/server -ljvm
Updating Java configuration in /usr/lib/R
Done.
```

Please let me know what I'm missing.

Comment: Change your `JAVA_HOME` environment variable to the `java-8 jvm` directory.

Comment: @abdou Thanks. When I echo $JAVA_HOME i get

     /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64

Comment: Chris, Dirk's answer is quite encompassing. I am surprised it does not solve the issue. But you can try and set the `JAVA_HOME` variable in the .Rprofile file to the `java-8 jvm` directory. I really doubt that it will make much difference, but it is something to try, at least.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem: `java -version` gave Java 8, but `sudo R CMD javareconf` gave Java 7.

Running `sudo R CMD javareconf --help` gives:

```
Environment variables that can be used to influence the detection:
JAVA           path to a Java interpreter executable
               By default first 'java' command found on the PATH
               is taken (unless JAVA_HOME is also specified).
JAVA_HOME      home of the Java environment. If not specified,
               it will be detected automatically from the Java
               interpreter.
```

The documentation tells us to do what Dirk suggested: ensure that the first `java` found on `PATH` is the one we want. That did not help in my case, even though `JAVA_HOME` was not set. Abdou's suggestion of setting `JAVA_HOME` in my `.Rprofile` dit not help either.

To solve the problem, I had to set *root's* `JAVA_HOME` to the one I wanted (because `R CMD javareconf` is run as sudo):

```
sudo -i
export JAVA_HOME=$(dirname $(dirname $(readlink -f $(which javac))))
R CMD javareconf
exit
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue with `rJava` on Ububtu 14.04. Changing the first line in file `/usr/lib/R/etc/javaconf` to `: ${JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java}` and running `sudo R CMD javareconf`solved the issue in my case.

Answer (score 1):

I think 'all' you need to do is to

1. ensure your 'new' Java comes first in the `$PATH`; its installer may have appended to the end -- so correct that.
2. ensure you run `sudo R CMD javareconf` with that path.

Taking these two together maybe

```
PATH=/opt/java/whatever/bin:$PATH sudo R CMD javareconf
```

is all it takes.  Adjust the path on that like as needed.

Lastly, `rJava` from source may not be needed. I do `sudo apt-get install r-cran-rjava`.

Comment: Thanks Dirk. I have done this with no luck. Still using java 7 for R

Comment: Hm.  I think this worked for me once when some other software stack needed a different/newer Java.